# Microcontroller input state counter problem

Tags: c, timer, embedded, counter, pic

I am doing a major embedded project of making a GM counter. As a main microcontroller I am using a PIC32MK1024MCM064. I wont bore you with details, but I need to implement following algorithm:

1. When MCU turns on, 13 seconds delay has to pass
2. MCU waits for a button press, which triggers an interrupt
3. Button interrupt starts 60 seconds timer
4. During that 60 seconds, MCU input pin counts the impulses (Idle voltage state is high (3.3V) and low voltage state counts as an impulse (50-130 us duration))
5. After the timer has expired, MCU outputs the impulse number via 16x2 LCD screen

Project has many files included in it, but I have already verified all the peripheral code is written right:

I have already made sure, that my button interrupt and the timer interrupt work absolutely fine (used the oscilloscope, real timer and all the other stuff.)

I also verified that my I2C driver for the LCD screen works great as well.

I made sure I am indeed getting the low state impulses as defined (50-130 us duration.)

```
 #include <xc.h> 
#include "configurations_bits.h"
       
#include <stddef.h>                    
#include <stdint.h>                    
#include <stdbool.h>                    
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "stdio.h" 
#include <sys/attribs.h> 

#include "delay.h"
#include "inter_integrated_circuit_protocol.h" 
#include "liquid_crystal_display.h" 
#include "pulse_width_modulation.h" 
#include "timer.h" 
#include "state_change_interrupts.h" 
 
static int  Particle_count = 0;                                //Variable for counting events 
 
 char Value[10]={0};                                           //Particle value string
 
    int main(void) {
        
        __builtin_disable_interrupts();                        //Global interrupt disable 
        
        ANSELA = 0x00000000;                                   //Enable PORT A digital inputs 
        ANSELG = 0x00000000;                                   //Enable PORT G digital inputs  
       
        TRISEbits.TRISE12 = 0;                                 //Output gpio of a led
        TRISDbits.TRISD8 = 0;                                  //Output gpio of a led
        TRISGbits.TRISG9 = 0;                                  //Output GPIO of GM ENABLE  
        
        LATGbits.LATG9 = 1;                                    //Enable GM right away
        TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 1;                                  //Input for counting particles  
        TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1;                                  //Input for control button
        
        Inter_Integrated_Circuit_Setup ();                     //I2C configuration
        Inter_Integrated_Circuit_Enable ();                    //I2C enable
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_initialization();               //LCD configuration
        
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(1, 1);
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String("Preparing for");
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(2, 1);
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String("Measurement");
         
        Pulse_Width_Modulation_Setup();                        //PWM setup
        Pulse_Width_Modulation_Enable();                       //Turn on high voltage generation
         
        for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
        delay_ms(1000);}                                       //Waiting until the high voltage rail rises up to 400V (starting GM tube voltage)   
        
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Clear();                        //Clearing LCD
        
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(1, 1);
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String("Ready for");
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(2, 1);
        Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String("Measurement");
        
        State_Change_Interrupts_Setup ();                      //Button interrupt setup
        Timer2_Setup ();                                       //Timer interrupt setup
        
        __builtin_enable_interrupts();                         //Global interrupt enable
        
            while (1){
              
                 if(T2CONbits.ON){                             //Condition, that the timer is on
                     
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Clear();            //Clearing LCD
                    
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(1, 1);
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String(" Measurement Is ");
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(2, 1);
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String("  In Progress   ");
                    
                    while(T2CONbits.ON){                         //Execute this while cycle until the timer shuts off
                        if(PORTAbits.RA1==0){
                        Particle_count = Particle_count+1;  
                        delay_us(100);}                         //GM tube dead time compensation 
                    }                        
                    
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Clear();            //Clearing LCD
                    
                    sprintf(Value,"%05d CPM",Particle_count);
                     
                    Particle_count=0;                          //Resetting the CPM value
                                            
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Set_Cursor(1, 1);
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Write_String(Value);//Printing radiation level in CPM notation    
                    delay_ms(5000);
                    
                    Liquid_Crystal_Display_Clear();            //Clearing LCD
                 }
            }
            
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        
    }
```

When I press the button, my LCD outputs "Measurement Is In Progress" for a fraction of a second, then it immediately outputs "00000 CPM" which means it had counted zero impulses (In my application, I know for sure that I must capture at least 5 impulses per minute.) Looks like the while cycle has only one or few iterations (it should last for a minute). So my code problem is not a missing semicolon somewhere, but I feel like the whole architecture is not right. Have you got any observations or suggestions, how could I implement the mentioned algorithm? Want to thank you in advance.

(P.S I am running a 8 MHz internal FRC as the main clock)

Comment: Aside note that `sprintf(Value, "%05d CPM", Particle_count);` will overflow the buffer if `Particle_count > 99999`. That formatting controls the *minimum* field width, not its maximum.

Comment: In your outer `while` loop, you do `if (T2CONbits.ON) {`. If that is true, eventually you loop on it: `while (T2CONbits.ON) {` Since you get your CPM output message, this means that `TS2CONbits.ON` goes to zero. So, after the first time that `ON` goes to 0, what sets it back to 1? I don't see any code for that. So, I assume that the timer is self rearming??? Can you prove/verify that after `ON` goes to 0, it eventually goes back to 1? Otherwise, after the first time, the outer loop degenerates into a glorified spinloop. The first measurement might be short due to startup conditions.

Comment: Do you have some way to get debug output (e.g. UART)? Or, can part of the display show program's current state (e.g. states are numbers)? Or, do you have a debugger of some sort?

Comment: The thing is that, I have a verification led blink in the timer interrupt. It goes like:
I press the button -> it starts the 60s timer -> after 60 seconds I see the led blink. So the T2CONbits.ON has to be logical one all the time (60 seconds), otherwise, I would not see the led blink. But right after the button press, I also get the described result (instantaneous 00000 CPM message) I have an MPLab Pickit4 programmer debugger but it looks really complicated to use for me personally.

Comment: Regarding startup, after every system launch, there is that inevitable 13 seconds delay, so the system has to be running perfectly stable after that delay. So your guess is that T2CONbits.ON still somehow becomes logical zero? From a C perspective it looks absolutely logical to me as well, but I am getting that led blink after 60 seconds, which is implemented in the timer ISR, so I know, that timer would not run if T2CONbits.ON was logical zero...

Comment: What is more, even if I used debugger, how could I simulate a button press? Because all this is initiated by a button press, without it, it is worthless even try debugging

Comment: Please reduce your program to a [mre] to investigate this further. Some code we don't see resets `T2CONbits.ON`, and that might be really fast.

Comment: You sure, you properly configured the port pin? You sure that PORTA pin is triggered properly and you see the register bit toggle? And btw, stop writing novels, there are common abbreviations like I2C, LCD, PWM.

Comment: Why don't you setup TIMER2 for the 60 seconds just before the loop?  The fact that it's not there would bother me.  What I mean is that obviously the delay is configired  somewhere else, this brings uncertainty (and in this case, I believe a bug as well)

Comment: Also, 60 seconds is very long, have you tried decrementing a counter instead of stopping the timer from the interrupt?